# Selecting All Rows in SQL, With Specific Criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a fairly complicated `SQL` statement I am working on. Here is where I am at:

```
 SELECT  c.category
              FROM master_cat as c
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT cat_id, user_id COUNT(cat_id) favoriteCat
                FROM ratings
                GROUP BY user_id
            ) a ON a.cat_id= c.cat_id
        LEFT JOIN users AS u  
            ON  u.user_id AND a.user_id

WHERE u.username = '{$user}' LIMIT 1
```

This statement is incomplete.  I am missing a middle table here.  `cat_id` is not actually in `ratings`.  But `items_id` is from a table called `items` and `cat_id` is also in that table as well.

So what I am trying to do is this:

```
SELECT rating FROM ??? GROUP BY cat_id where u.user=$user
```

The only thing I can think of doing maybe is another LEFT join with `items` inside `favoriteCat` but I am not sure if that is allowed.

Comment: You are using MySql? Please add the relevant DBMS tag. Can you also add a (simple) table scheme with the relevant columns? I think your description holds all the information, but it tends to be a bit cryptic.

Comment: Yes you are allowed to do inner or left join there, just try. Join it to `ratings` within `a` subquery

Comment: You WHERE condition effectively renders the LEFT [OUTER] JOIN as an [INNER] JOIN, so if that's what you want you may as well write it that way!

Comment: posted final solution.. decided to redo from scratch and make it ... less complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking this, here is my final solution:

```
SELECT  c.category,   count(r.rating) AS totalCount
FROM ratings as r
LEFT JOIN items AS i
   ON i.items_id = r.item_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u
   ON u.user_id = r.user_id
LEFT JOIN master_cat AS c
   ON c.cat_id = i.cat_id
WHERE  r.user_id = '{$user_id}'
GROUP BY c.category
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
```